# Rangy - restore cursor position when replacing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom, rangy

I am using Rangy to select and restore the cursor position.

It does an excellent job but it has not been designed for when user input is manipulated programmatically and a shorter string is replaced in the innerHTML of the DIV.

I created an example on jsbin showing what happens when user types a space at the end of the selection and the space is stripped out programmatically:
http://jsbin.com/ebeqoj/4/edit

The replaced innerHTML is shorter than the one Rangy tries to restore so it fails and the DIV loses focus.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to handle this. For example, is there a way to instruct Rangy to restore the cursor at the end of the new string? (I have tried using  `rangy.getSelection().move("character", userInput2.length-1)`without success)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the caret at the end of the contents of the `<div>` is quite easy:

```
var sel = rangy.getSelection();
sel.selectAllChildren(el);
sel.collapseToEnd();
```

For the more general case, you can create a range that encompasses the content from the start of the `<div>` to the caret position, get its text using the `text()` method of Rangy ranges, remove white space from that text and measure its length. Demo:

http://jsbin.com/ebeqoj/5/edit